# Passing a string with quotes inside of it from API response as argument to a function in JS

Tags: javascript, string, api, arguments, quotes

I'm passing below data that i'm capturing from an API to the function addToList().

```
//...
onclick="addToList(\'' + value.id + '\',\'' + value.title + '\',\'' value.image_url + '\')"
//...

function addTolist (id, title, image_url)
{
    var data = {};
    data.id = id;
    data.title = title;
    data.image_url = image_url;    
    data.format = "json";
    $.ajax({
              //...
}
```

My problem is that certain titles do have quotes in it (e.g A Knight's Tale) and i'm getting a syntax error because of it.

Is there a way to change the value that I'm capturing from value.title in order for it to be accepted as argument to my addToList function?

Thanks

Comment: You should use an event instead of the onclick attribute

Comment: How can I pass the arguments then?

Comment: Use an event and retrieve the value either by the event object, or get the element by an id

Comment: Hi adding an event doesn't really solve how i capture the strings that have single quotes in them. My problem lies in the fact that the value i'm getting back from my json request {title : "Text with ' in it } is not being handled correctly by js"

Comment: Alright i just had to escape(title) and i can pass it as an argument :)